# Filter out small images in PHP - speedily

Tags: php, image, web-scraping

I have an image scraper written in PHP which works very well and quickly. The problem is that when I run getimagesize() on these external images things slow way down. How can I eliminate results below a certain size threshold without compromising speed?

Comment: unfortunately the curl method is still much slower than my application can accept. I think i'll wind up using a series of regex and transparency tests to eliminate spacer images...